# Using Java's File.delete() method

Tags: java, java-io

When I used the `File.delete()` method to delete a file, where is the deleted file? I am using a Mac and I don't see the file in the Trash. I want to know where the file is being stored at? Or if it is permanently gone.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's gone. The trash bin is just a temporary place where files are put before being deleted, when you "delete" them through the OS.

In most filesystems, however, deleting a file only removes the pointer to it from the system's list of files. The actual data may sit on the harddrive for a significant amount of time until it is overwritten. There are file recovery tools available that can attempt to retrieve such files, but they are not 100% sucesfull.

Answer (score 3):

The trash in Mac/Linux (or Recycle Bin, in Windows) only work with the specific file managers (Finder, Nautilus/Dolphin or Explorer) where they actually move a file into a temporary folder on the same partition (aka  Trash / Recycle Bin), from where it's deleted.

From the core OS's point of you, delete() will permanently delete it.

Answer (score 1):

> where the file is being stored?

It isn't. You deleted it. It's deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Calling File.[delete](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29)() permanently removes the file, without going into the recycling bin or anything similar.