# Can we undo file.delete() function in java?

Tags: java, file

I was trying to delete some duplicate files in my folder which is around 230GB. Therefore, I searched for files with the names _2 or _3 and use the

```
file.delete();
```

However, it deletes the files that I wasn't expecting it. Can I undo that process or are those files deleted permanantly?

Comment: What did you find when you googled "file recovery"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Files are gone. See this Question below

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106850/using-javas-file-delete-method
```

So, about the workaround, If this was on windows, using recovery tools like "File Scavenger" might help you out.

Comment: thanks i will mark this as duplicate then.